# variable error in function while assignment

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Write a Python script to sort (ascending and descending) a dictionary by value

```
def sort_dictionary_ascending(dict):
    flag = True
    list = []
    while(len(dict)!=1):
        flag = True
        for x,y in dict.items():
            if flag:
                min = x
                flag = False
            elif min>x:
                min =x;
        list.append(min)
        dict.pop(min)
    min,value= dict.popitem()
    list.append(min)
    print(list)
def sort_dictionary_descending(dict):
    flag = True
    list = []
    while(len(dict)!=1):
        flag = True
        for x,y in dict.items():
            if flag:
                max = x
                flag = False
            elif max < x:
                max = x
        list.append(max)
        dict.pop(max)
    max,value= dict.popitem()
    list.append(max)
    print(list)
d = {1: 1, 3: 3, 4: 4, 2: 2, 5: 5}
sort_dictionary_descending(d)
sort_dictionary_ascending(d)
```

Error is:

```
/home/admin2/Desktop/two/venv/bin/python /home/admin2/Desktop/two/sort_dictionary.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin2/Desktop/two/sort_dictionary.py", line 45, in <module>
    sort_dictionary_ascending(d)
  File "/home/admin2/Desktop/two/sort_dictionary.py", line 17, in sort_dictionary_ascending
    list.append(min)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'min' referenced before assignment
[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: There are much simpler ways to sort a dictionary.

Comment: You emptied the original dict `d` when first calling `sort_dictionary_descending(d)`, so when you call `sort_dictionary_ascending(d)`,  `while(len(dict)!=1):` is never executed and 
`min` never gets defined. Note that your choices of variable names are really bad: you should not use the names of Python builtins as variable names, this will shadow the original function (dict, list, min, max...)

Comment: Don't use `dict` as a variable or parameter name because it's a built-in type.

Answer (score 0):

First in your for loops use `for x in dict.keys()` instead of `for x, y in dict.items()`
because `y` variable isn't used in the whole loop. Second, I don't understand why you use a dict which the key is equal to the value, a list is more suitable

Comment: I have to sort dictionary without use of built in fuctions